# How to save output of elif to a csv file in python?

Tags: python

```
import csv
with open("input.csv") as f:
    d1 = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(f)]
for x in d1:
    if 0<=int(x)<30:
        print("0<=x<30".format(x))
    elif 40<=int(x)<120:
        print("40<=x<120")
```

My code is shown above, and I am trying to save the output in a .csv file. Is there any solution to send data from `elif` to `csv.writer`?

Comment: Please do read the documentation. Everything that you need for this question is right there: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: As a note/hint: The way you word your problem also makes me worried about your understanding of `if`/`elif`. You do not "send" data from the `elif` statement. It is just a conditional statement and the code inside will be executed if the condition is fulfilled. The code inside the statement is no different than outside, so you do not have to "send" anything.

Comment: yes I know, but I question is how to write "someiterable" instead of x in d2.writerow(x)!? @Eduard Daduya

Comment: @mwormser, no I mean making the out put!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `open('output.csv', 'w').write("40<=%s<120"%(x))` after your print statement in the `elif` section.

Answer (score 1):

You just reopen with csv.writer like so:

```
d2 = csv.writer(f)
d2.writerow(x)
```

and read the documentation linked by @Eduard Daduya !!!!!!

Comment: yes I know, but I question is how to write "someiterable" instead of x in d2.writerow(x)!? @user2740652